# Where are ORM's vulnerable for SQL injection?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, orm, sql-injection

When using ORM's (Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, NHibernate ...), are SQL injection attacks mitigated by design?

If not, where should I be doing some extra validation/scrubbing to prevent a vulnerability?

Comment: If not, they are a pretty lousy ORM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most, if not all, mainstream ORMs use parametrized SQL, which will protect you from a direct SQL injection attack. However parametrized SQL at the application layer will not protect you from latent SQL injection attacks. These occur when something down the line, other than the ORM, directly concatenates user input in a SQL statement (such as a batch run stored procedure that concatenates user input to create a non-parametrized dynamic query). Note that this isn't an ORM issue at all, but I thought I'd bring it up to point out that parametrized SQL only protects you from injections if it is used everywhere, not just in the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

They are in NHibernate by using parameterized queries.

Answer (score -3):

ORMs are designed to be secure, in the basic concepts. Most of the time you'll not have to worry about it, but if you think you might be exposed to real cracking you should do some custom tunning.

For simple apps, simple SQL injection you'll be cover. No body (seriously, no body ever) will give you a silver bullet in matters of security and SQL Injection. That's my advice.

Comment: Custom tunning? What are you talking about?

Comment: Get in the source code, in every little aspect of the configuration, etc. I't seems you've never done this...

Comment: unless you give me a concrete example of tuning that you had to do, I'll assume you are just trying to sound like a security expert without being one.

Answer (score -3):

ORMs typically use a lot of dynamic SQL, which is insecure because it gives users of the application and/or service accounts the ability to execute ad-hoc SQL queries.  The correct solution is for only Programmers and DB Admins to have DataReader/DataWriter and all programs that touch the database to use nothing except parameterized Stored Procedures always with no DataReader/DataWriter access associated with the program.  They can only access the SPs I say they can.  Only the DB Admins and Programmers should be able execute ad-hoc SQL queries.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of such an application that is using Stored Procedures no DataReader/DataWriter access associated with the program? thank you.

Comment: I have several applications at work that have a Data Access Layer that calls nothing except SPs and the only people with DataReader/DataWriter are me and the DB Admin.  The User Accounts/ Sevice Accounts will all fail on a SELECT * FROM MyTable type of statement unless I create a Stored Procedure named that and grant them execution rights.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with SELECT * FROM MyTable type of statement, you know

Comment: The only way I see SELECT * FROM MyTable as safe is if there is no concatenation and the string is literal and hard-coded.  That is the only way I would trust it.  The second parameters are used to construct it, who knows what happens when whatever resulting string literal gets submitted to the DB. Actually, the problem can be solved by not letting anyone submit ad-hoc SQL queries from random users in the first place.  If anyone other that a DB Admin or Programmer on a very short list wants to hit the SP, they use an existing DB or make a request.

Comment: don't you have such queries inside your procedures, do you?

Comment: If they are inside my Stored Procedures, any user input is submitted as a parameter.  If the user somehow submits SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable as a raw statement, it will fail.  They can execute only the SPs I say they can.  If they want some data, they talk to their manager, who makes a work order which travels through my manager, then me, then the DB Admins manager, then the DB Admin, then finally back to the user.  The SP then goes live after it travels through Test, QA, Integration, and Production.

Comment: Well if you have spare money to feed all the bunch - why not. However, your idea on ORMs is quite wrong.